# Continuous Recognition With Authorization Token Async With Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech` for continuous synchronization. In continuous synchronization process needs Token. When I use this method to access token , it work fine with console application. If I apply same method in .NET web application, It never reruns the token. Need your help.
I have tried with console app, it work fine.

```
// Gets an authorization token by sending a POST request to the token service.
public static async Task<string> GetToken(string subscriptionKey, string region)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("https://" + region + ".api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken");

        using (var result = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, null))
        {

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException($"Cannot get token from {uriBuilder.ToString()}. Error: {result.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this point, It never returns. Using `(var result = await client.PostAsync(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri, null))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .Result or .Wait or await this will end up causing a deadlock in your code.

you can use ConfigureAwait(false) in async methods for preventing deadlock

like this:

response = await client.PostAsync(uri, RoleContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
you can use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever possible for Don't Block Async Code .